# Liquibase rollback when maven build failed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle, liquibase

How to rollback liquibase changeset automatically when maven build failed due to some reason like any test failed or some other reason.

I am using below configuration in liquibase.

```
<changeSet id="1" author="Manish">
        <createTable tableName="person2">
            <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Is there a way to rollback this if build failed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rollback a changeset. For that you will need to do 2 things as below:

1. Add a rollback code in the changeset. Refer to the video in [this document](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/pro/rollbackonechangeset.html?Highlight=rollback) to learn how you can add the rollback code.
2. You will need to run the rollback command from one of the Maven goals. You can learn more about the Maven goals on this document: https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-rollback.html

Comment: Is there a way to automatically rollback without using mvn command whenever build fails?

Comment: @ManishBansal you found a way?